# Subclasses of generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, interface

When I have for example an interface `Drivable` and a class `Car` which implements that interface. If I make a class with generic type `Garage<T extends Drivable>`, is it possible to make a new `Garage<Car>` or does inheritance not work with generic types and should it be `Garage<Drivable>`?

Comment: What happened when you tried ??

Comment: Works for me, I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what types of `Drivable` you want to put into the `Garage`'  If you want to be able to put any type of `Drivable` into the `Garage`, then declare it as `Garage<Drivable>`.  If you only ever want that particular instance to contain `Car` instances that it's perfectly acceptable to declare it as `Garage<Car>`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class `Garage<T extends Drivable>`, it means that `Garage` can accept classes which implements `Drivable` or sub-interfaces of `Drivable` or classes that implement sub-interfaces of `Drivable`. Basically, it checks if the class IS-A `Drivable`. In this case, since `Car` IS-A `Drivable`, you can have a `Garage<Car>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can instantiate an object of type `Garage<Car>`, because `Car` implements the required `Drivable` interface, and therefore meets the generic type constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to make a `Garage<Car>`.

However, a `Garage<Car>` is not a subclass of `Garage<Drivable>`.  To see why, imagine if it was - then the following code would compile:

```
public void putBikeAway(Motorbike bike, Garage<Driveable> garage) {
    garage.parkVehicle(bike);
}

Garage<Car> garage = new Garage<Car>();
Garage<Drivable> dgarage = garage; // doesn't compile in reality
Motorbike b = new Motorbike();
putBikeAway(b, dgarage);
// We now have a Motorbike in a Garage<Car>!

// So later on...
Car car = garage.getVehicle(); // throws ClassCastException at runtime
```

For that reason, a `Garage<Car>` is **not** an instance of `Garage<Drivable>` (because if it were you could add a `Motorbike` to it, and the generic type safety is completely subverted).  Instead, a compile time error will be thrown on line 6 in my example.